# How to add "clipboard-write" permission to navigator?

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I am maintaining an app written in Angular and launched on chromium (desktop app), i am trying to copy to clipboard some text and i used

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(result)
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work because and i don't have "clipboard-write" permission on the navigator.

How to add permission "clipboard-write" to the browser (embedded browser on a desktop application (chromium)) or is there any other solution to copy the text to the clipboard ?

Comment: no it's onther techonology, delphi and dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to add permission "clipboard-write" to the navigator?

Permissions are not something that you (as the developer) control. They are entirely within the control of the user and user agent (browser). If the user decides not to grant (or revoke) a permission, then your app simply cannot perform actions which require it.

I'll inline some documentation from the MDN article for [`Clipboard.writeText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText#security):

> ### Security
>
> [Transient user activation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation) is required. The user has to interact with the page or a UI element in order for this feature to work.
>
> The `"clipboard-write"` permission of the [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) is granted automatically to pages when they are in the active tab.

Comment: it is not a ordinary navigator, it's a chromium embedded on a desktop application, does that change anything ?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74774213/how-to-add-clipboard-write-permission-to-navigator/74774295?noredirect=1#comment131966639_74774295) @VenomBerry In that case, it's up to the software that is responsible for embedding Chromium to configure and manage the permissions on behalf of the user. You should consult the documentation of that software to understand how to use it to configure/modify permissions. Your question [didn't](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74774213/1) mention anything about embedding Chromium, but that's a critical detail.